# Returning pointer from function and saving it

Tags: c

I printed out the value of e.val in main before and after the call to function, and the value has been changed. 
I am new to C, so wanted to understand this a little better.

Since I return the new pointer and assign it back to e.val, e.val's value changes.

Questions:

1) Is returning and assigning a new value to e.val basically the same as passing a double pointer to e.val?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct{

  int * val;

} Event;

//qdsp_classic
int* function(int * ptr);
int* function2();
int main()
{
    Event e;
    int x = 10;
    e.val = &x; 
    printf("orig%p\n", (void *) (e.val));
    e.val = function(e.val);
    printf("New%p\n", (void *) (e.val));
    return 0;
}
int* function(int * ptr) 
{
    ptr = function2();
    printf("%p\n", (void *) ptr);
    return ptr;
}
int* function2() 
    int num = 100;
    int * newPtr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    return newPtr;
}
```

Comment: The "value" of `e.val` is changing not the "address".

Comment: The value of e.val is where it points to correct? So, we are changing what e.val points to, not where e.val is located in memory.

Comment: Exactly! You are changing the address it contains. Not it's address.

Comment: Thanks. So if I add this line: *newPtr = 80; in function2(), my e.val will have same value as newPtr and both newPtr and e.val will point to 80.

Comment: Yes, but to better phrase it - *both newPtr and e.val will point to a memory that contains the integer 80*

Answer (score 4):

If you create instance of struct `Event`, its allocated on stack and pointer inside has *immediate* value -> dereferencing would cause undefined behavior. Variable `x` is on stack aswell and has value `10`.

```
+-------------+
|             |
|    +---+    |                   +----+
|    | * |    |                   | 10 |
|    +---+    |                   +----+
|   int* val  |                     x
+-------------+
    Event e
```

After assignment `e.val = &x;` to pointer `val` is saved address of variable `x` (In other words `val` is pointing on `x`)

```
+-------------+
|             |
|    +---+    |                   +----+
|    | * |----|------------------>| 10 |
|    +---+    |                   +----+
|   int* val  |                     x
+-------------+
    Event e
```

`int * newPtr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));` Creates one `int` on `heap` / *dynamic storage duration*, which is uninitialized and his address (address of first byte) is saved to pointer variable `newPtr`.

```
+-------------+                                    HEAP
|             |                                    ----------------
|    +---+    |                   +----+           +---+
|    | * |----|------------------>| 10 |           | ? |
|    +---+    |                   +----+           +---+
|   int* val  |                     x                ^
+-------------+                                      |
    Event e                                          |
                                                     |
     +---+                                           |
     | * |--------------------------------------------
     +---+
  int* newPtr
```

`newPtr` is returned and saved to `e.val.` which means that `e.val` is no longer pointing on `x` but since now is pointing on that `int` on heap.

```
+-------------+                                    HEAP
|             |                                    ----------------
|    +---+    |                   +----+           +---+
|    | * |----|-------            | 10 |           | ? |
|    +---+    |      |            +----+           +---+
|   int* val  |      |              x                ^
+-------------+      |                               |
    Event e          ---------------------------------
```

Its also possible to change where does pointer points by passing `**` double pointer.

```
void function(int ** ptr) 
{
    *ptr = function2();
    printf("%p\n", (void *) *ptr);
}

// In main
function(&e.val);
```

Comment: So, using double pointer and returning new value in this case are equivalent, correct?

Comment: @FilipKočica how did you draw the boxes ?

Comment: Click on `edit` and look yourself, but dont save changes please :-)